# How to set the background of a WPF grid to an image in local folder?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a small WPF application and I'm trying to change the background of a grid to an image the user chooses (stored somewhere on the computer on a different location from the app). Is it possible without having the images included on the project and marked as a Resource? How?

Comment: What do you mean "change the color based on an image?" Like select the top-left pixel of the image and use that?

Comment: It was a typo, corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you `Grid` name is `grid`, then xaml would be:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
...
</Grid>
```

then to set an image programatically to `grid`, you should use the following code snippet:

```
 string imgPath=@"E:\anImage.jpg";
 grid.Background= new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgPath,
                                                   UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };
```

Comment: With `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` it would also work with an absolute file path.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set the image's source URI to the image location

```
<Image Source="<<URI of image>>"/>

<ImageBrush ImageSource="<<URI of image>>"/>
```

or you can do the same via binding to allow it to be customised

```
<Image Source="{Binding Data}"/>
```

in this example Data is a byte[] stored in the model, but could be anything that converts to an image source

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :
1) Add image in solution (Add => Existing Item)

2)`<Grid>
      <Grid.Background> 
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/App;component/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
            </ImageBrush>
      </Grid.Background>
   </Grid>`